# django type object Http404 has no attribute get

Tags: python, django

I have this code:

```
if not selected_organization in request.user.organizations.all():
        return Http404
```

while returning the http 404 I got this :

```
type object 'Http404' has no attribute 'get'
```

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Took me a while to figure out,

Eventually I had to `raise` the `Http404` and not `return` it!

Comment: Thanks for saving me from bashing my head on screen.

Comment: Thank you! I was returning the Http404 too not realizing it's an exception lol.

Answer (score 11):

return Http404() ==> is a wrong

raise Http404()  ==> is a correct

((under _ example code))

```py
def room_detail(request, pk):
    try:
        room = models.Room.objects.get(pk=pk)        
        return render(request, "rooms/detail.html", {"room": room})
    except models.Room.DoesNotExist:
        raiseHttp404()
```

Comment: please add the formatting to the code, it helps others to understand  and differentiate the code snippet easily